# Fill a region between horizontal lines and curves

Tags: plotting, filling

How can I fill the region between two horizontal lines and two curves like the following?

[image: plot with hand drawn sketch of result]

```
Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], GridLines -> {{}, {1, -1}}, 
GridLinesStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[97][1]}]
```

Comment: See [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1273995) for a related discussion, but it is a few years old.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Plot[{1, -1}, {b, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}}],
  Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> White]
  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

```
Clear[plot, pts];
 plot = 
 Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2];
pts = Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
(*Graphics[{Polygon[Join[pts[[1]],pts[[2]]]],Polygon[Join[pts[[3]],\
pts[[4]]]]}]*)
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[Green], 
  Polygon@Join[pts[[1]], Reverse@pts[[3]], Reverse@pts[[4]], 
    pts[[2]]]}, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 10] /. {___, Line[pts1_], 
   Line[pts2_]} -> {FaceForm@Green, Polygon@Join[pts1, pts2]}
```

```
ContourPlot[
  x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] /. {__, Line[pts1_], 
   Line[pts2_]} :> {FaceForm@Green, EdgeForm@Blue, 
   Polygon@Join[pts1, pts2]}
```

**Original**

Use `RegionDifference` to get the complement of `Filling -> {1 -> {2}`.

```
plot0 = Plot[{-Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]

reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-4, -1}, {4, 1}], 
   DiscretizeGraphics[plot0]];
plot = Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2]}, {b, -4, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Orange, reg}]]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This sets the background to LightBlue and then fills everything but the center region white.

```
Plot[{Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2], -Sqrt[(b^2 - 1)/b^2],1,-1}, {b, -4.08, 4.08}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1],Background->LightBlue,Filling->{1->{{2},White},3->{Top,White},4->{Bottom,White}},PlotRangePadding->None,ImagePadding->None,PlotRange->{-1.08,1.08}]
```

[image]